# Is there a way in Vim to draw the visual area of the same size as the last visual selection, but at a new cursor position?

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

After I visually select the following area
[image]

And press Esc and move this position
[image]

I want to be able to select the same shape in this manner
[image]

If there is no generic and direct way to do this, any tips on how to code a vimscript function for this will also be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this feature is there, but it's a bit hidden. From `:help v`:

```
[count]v            Start Visual mode per character.
                    With [count] select the same number of characters or
                    lines as used for the last Visual operation, but at
                    the current cursor position, multiplied by [count].
```

So, if you specify a count of 1 (`1v`), the same number of character as the last selection had is used, but at the current cursor position.

Comment: This sort of works, but only "saves" the number of characters if you perform a *visual operation*. If you escape Visual Mode without performing an operation (yank, for example), it does not retain the character count.

Comment: It works as described by @SirBraneDamuj. Is it possible to get the same functionality without performing an operation as well?

Comment: You could perform a null operation to force the "save". For example `"_y`